# How to dispose a crystal report -in load or unload event?

Tags: crystal-reports

I am new to crystal report. How to dispose reports using the following methods.

```
 report.Close();
 report.Dispose();
```

Do i have to use it in Load or in Unload events of crystal report viewer?
Can anyone suggest a way to dispose report?

Answer (score 0):

I always use the FormClosed event of the form that is hosting the report viewer.

```
   private void CrystalPreviewForm_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {

                if (this.reportDocument != null)
                {
                    this.reportDocument.Close();
                    this.reportDocument.Dispose();
                }

        }
```